# Number of displayed questions/page when having ignored tags

Tags: feature-request, ignored-tags

After starting to add ignored tags, I noticed that I no longer see the requested 50 questions/page; so it seems that the number displayed is actually calculated as (number of questions requested - number of questions not displayed as on ignored tag list).

Wouldn't it be more useful to display always the requested number of questions? The number of displayed questions/page is starting to be tiny.